# How do I close the gap in a mask inside UV/Image Editor?

Tags: uv-image-editor, masking

This is my very first time of using masks and I am testing masks. I want to know how to mask areas of a video. FYI, I am new to mask nodes. 
For any assistance, thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to *Toggle Cyclic*, which closes the selected splines. Pressing it again will re-open the mask spline.

This is also found in the *Toolshelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) in the *Mask* tab> *Mask Tools*> *Spline* section or in the *UV/Image Editor* header under *Mask*> *Toggle Cyclic*.

Comment: If this has helped, you can 'accept' the answer. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I just re-edited my question. Now, I'm wonder how to remove the shaded area outside the maroon mask and how to lay cropped mask up top of video. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have another question this should be asked as a new, separate question, not an edit to an existing one.